# RabbitMQ : mark message as obsolete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message, rabbitmq

Global question : can we mark a message as obsolete before it consummed by a client ?

Context:

- I have a cluster of machines
- Each machine send message when something change
- The message is a Rails object that changed
- The client, when getting this message, juste save it

Scenario

- Given 3 machines A, B and C
- Given the object O belongs to machine A
- A is out of network
- There is lot of changes on object O on machine A

When network is up again, I'd like to cancel all the messages regarding O, except the last one (producer side or consummer side).
So B and C will not save all the states of the O object, but only the last one.

Questions :

- Do you think it is possible ?
- Is there a better way to achieve syncronisation (we don't want to use MySQL cluster)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

we are doing something silimar (in .net but) if a node goes off network or restarts then when it comes back the first thing it does is ask all the other nodes to a status upadte.  All the node send this to all nodes.  We then use a time stamp to only act on a message if its more recent than the last last one processed.  Appears to work just fine for what we need which is 5 worker nodes all with the same configuration and syncing any chnages between themselves.

Comment: In fact, we have a cluster of machine with durable queues and messages. So when node is up again, it receive all missed messages automatically (AMQP logic).

But I don't want the node to process more than x old messages. Because message #1001 could obsolete messages #900, #850, #800 ...

I guess the best option would be to clean up my queue if there is more messages than potential messages targets. This would indicate that there are probably obsoletes messages and that it could be lighter to totally reinitialize state...